# How do i restore directly from a Crashplan backup destination hard drive on another computer?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, crashplan, system-recovery

I don't know if my title managed to describe my question, so here is an example: Suppose i have two home computers A and B both running e.g. windows 7. B is my home server, and it has an extra hard drive just for files (no OS). Lets say I do my Crashplan backups from A to the file drive on B.

Assume that the B crashes, but that the file hard drive with the backup on it is still intact. At the same time A also crashes. I buy a new computer C with win 7 on which i want to restore the files stored on B:s intact drive to C. How do i do that with crashplan?

I don't seem to find an answer with google, if there is already an answer somewhere please post a link ;P. The closest thing seems to be crashplans adopt feature, but i don't understand how i should use that to do what i want.

Comment: The adopt feature is half of what you want. You'll want to tell C to "adopt" A's backups. That still leaves the question of how to access the backups on B, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key here is to attach your archive to the CrashPlan software on Computer C.

Basic Step-by-step:

1. Install CrashPlan on Computer C using existing un/pw
2. Attach backup archive from B using these instructions:

   http://support.crashplan.com/doku.php/how_to/attach_archive
3. Restore for Computer A from Computer C (it'll say "(this computer)" next to it)
4. If after restoring everything you want to continue backing up from Computer C as if it were Computer A, then you can adopt A to C. After adopting, CrashPlan will see that computer as Computer A, as if nothing had changed.

Don't adopt before restoring, it's unnecessary and can [make for a confusing restore.](https://helpdesk.crashplan.com/entries/23150532-Restoring-after-an-adoption)

Comment: Ok thx! Attaching archive was exactly was i was looking for, suppose I didn't find it myself since I was too focused on "hard drive" as a keyword and forgot that "Archive" is the proper crashplan term.